# woocommerce initialise shipping method, add to rates

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce I have the following situation: there are shipping methods before 100$, and after 100$ only one `(free shipping)` is available. So when a client buys a `product 102$` and then `apply the (10%) promo code`, the price will be 91,80$. Because I unset the shipping methods after 100$ and the free shipping appears `after 100$ only`, for the client shows: "There are no `shipping methods` available..."

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'woocommerce_hide_shipping', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_hide_shipping( $rates, $package ) {

  $threshold = 100;

if ( WC()->cart->subtotal >= $threshold ) {
    unset( $rates['flat_rate:45'] );
    unset( $rates['flat_rate:75'] );
}
if ( WC()->cart->subtotal >= $threshold && !empty(WC()->cart->applied_coupons) ) {
     //code here
}

  return $rates;

}
```

Its possible to show the free shipping if the `price was >100$` before promo code and a coupon was applied? I set up the free shipping to show a minimum order `amount (100$)` but there is a way to show, initialize? Other approaches are also welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is.... Free Shipping that you have applied is bounded by min order and that is referring to order total (NOT SUBTOTAL).....
Whereas subtotal gives you the value without discount.

So,

Remove condition (min order total) from your Admin settings - Free shipping.... Now it will work for every order...

Then modify your code ---

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'woocommerce_hide_shipping', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_hide_shipping( $rates, $package ) {

  $threshold = 100;

 if ( WC()->cart->subtotal >= $threshold ) {
    unset( $rates['flat_rate:45'] );
    unset( $rates['flat_rate:75'] );
}
if ( WC()->cart->subtotal < $threshold ) {
     //code here
     unset( $rates['free_shipping:45'] );
     unset( $rates['free_shipping:75'] );
}

  return $rates;

}
```